# sh: line 1: 5751 Segmentation fault sequelize db:migrate (Node.js + Sequelize + Postgresql)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, segmentation-fault, sequelize.js

Running `sequelize db:migrate` gives segmentation fault in elastic beanstalk.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
> sequelize db:migrate && node server.js


[4mSequelize CLI [Node: 10.16.0, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 5.8.7][24m

Loaded configuration file "sequelize/config/config.js".
Using environment "production".
sh: line 1: 10118 Segmentation fault      sequelize db:migrate
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 139
npm ERR! code@1.0.0 start: `sequelize db:migrate && node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 139
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the timeline_api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

> code@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
> sequelize db:migrate && node server.js
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the package `pg-native`. Switching `pg` solved the issue.

```
// Sequelize config
 production: {
    ...
    // or don't set this value.
    native: false,
    ...
  },
```

The problem also seems to with node version. Supposedly it doesn't work with `node 10` (Need more clarification).
Sources:

https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-native/issues/71

https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-native/issues/70